# How to specify alpha for imagemagick canvas with opqaue fill drawing objects

Tags: imagemagick

I'm trying to create a vignette filter in imagemagick. It has to be black and transparent for overlaying on other images in a browser (so I can't just composite by multiplying). Here's one way of doing it:

```
convert -size 300x300 xc:transparent -virtual-pixel background  -background black -blur 0x20 out.png
```

[image]

I'd prefer to use this function:

```
convert -size 300x300 xc: -fill black -fx '(1-(2*i/w-1)^4)*(1-(2*j/h-1)^4)' out.png
```

However, I can't seem to make the white transparent (just setting a transparent canvas doesn't work). How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

OK, got a solution:

Work only in the alpha channel, and make the vignette black and transparent in the center by subtracting it from 1 and negating.

```
convert -size 300x300 -alpha set -channel A xc: -fx '1- (1-(2*i/w-1)^4)*(1-(2*j/h-1)^4)' +channel -negate out.png
```

[image]